# How to stay on same form when submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h3>Student Log In</h3>
    <hr/>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="text-line"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Enter Your Password" class="text-line"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-warning"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h3>Student Sign Up</h3>
    <hr/>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" class="text-line"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Your Last Name" class="text-line"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p id="captImg"><?php echo $captchaImg; ?></p>
            <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" class="captcha" placeholder="Enter Image Inputs"/>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="refreshCaptcha" >Can't Read Please Refersh Image</a>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-warning"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here I have created a *sign in* and *sign up* form. When we click on *login*, *login form* is displayed. When we click on *sign up* it displays the *sign up form*. Now, I want that when I click on *submit* of *sign up form* then it goes to *login form*. How can I show only active or div either it will be *login form* or *signup form* on click *submit*?

Thank You

Comment: have you tried `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: I am not submit form data through jquery @MohhamadHasham

Comment: You have to give action like `<form action="demo.php"></form>`

Comment: When you have a form with no action specified, whenever you press a submit button, it will basically reload the page, or actually send the form data to the same page, but as you are not handling that data, it seems like you just refreshed the page.
You need to prevent this standard behaviour with `event.preventDefault()` in your JavaScript function as already suggested.

Comment: The question itself (How can I show only active or div either it will be login form or signup form on click submit?) doesn't sound quite clear, could you re-state it? Active what or which div? Is your question "How can I show only active or div?" and the other part is what actually happens? Please clarify. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Methods to this

add ID to your form name like "login-form" and put your login authentication code in a seperate file

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {  
     $('#login-form').on('submit',function (e) {

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'login_code.php',
            data: $('#login-form').serialize(),
            success: function (e) {
                //alert(e);
                switch(e)
                {
                    case "1":window.location.href = "home.php";
                        break;
                    case "2":$('#error').html('Username and password not match');
                        break;
                    default:$('#error').html('Username and password not match');
                        break;
                }

            }
          });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
        });
```

Or Just prevent the reload

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#login-form').on('submit',function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
  });
 }):
```